# backticks before bash command in shell

Tags: bash

What is the meaning of backticks before the bash command in the following manner?

````
```bash 
# Or
`bash
````

When I enter the following commands on my shell the following prompt 
appears

```
>
```

But if I enter

```
``bash
```

The `>` doesn't appear.

I came across this when following build-unix.md instructions for the bitcoin source code v0.15.1 in my text editor.

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v0.15.1/doc/build-unix.md

````
```bash
 BITCOIN_ROOT=$(pwd)
````

Thanks for your insights

Comment: There are no double backticks shown on (the formatted version of) that webpage. (Also, no `BITCOIN_ROOT=$(pwd)`.) So which page are you really referencing?

Comment: Ah. Your version of the software seems to be at least a year old. I would strongly suggest you get the current version instead of [0.13](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/0.13/doc/build-unix.md).

Comment: @roaima I was reading the document from my text editor, not the webpage which is why I was shown the GitHub markdown language backticks. I edited my answer to make that more clear. I was referencening the v0.15.1 tag, I have the right software. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is from github markdown language.  This should not be copied into your terminal.  In order to make a codeblock in github you surround your code with three backticks like so:

````
```
code
goes
here
```
````

In order to add syntax highlighting, you can specify the language like so:

````
```bash
code
goes
here
```
````

The code you want will be the stuff between the backticks.

---

The reason you are seeing the `>` prompt is because in bash the backticks are a special character used for command substitution.  (It's an outdated way to do it but still works).

You can use it like:

```
$ echo `hostname`
```

*it should be done like this*

```
$ echo "$(hostname)"
```

Which will echo the hostname of your machine.

However when bash sees one backtick it interprets the rest of the statement as command substitution until it reaches a closing backtick.  When you have three the first two close each other but the third opens opens a new substitution statement and bash is looking for a closing backtick.  When you hit enter it displays a `>` to let you know you are still inside this block and allow you to enter multi-line commands.  The same happens with quotes or the line escape character:

```
$ echo `
> hostname
> uname -s
> `
JBCGENS001 Linux
```

---

```
$ echo '
> hello
> world
> '

hello
world
```

---

```
$ echo \
> hello \
> world
hello world
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up! Would you also happen to know why I'm getting the  >  symbol after entering that input and what it means ?

Comment: @HamsterDancer:  I have updated my question