# What does the backtick before/after dollar sign mean?

Tags: bash

I saw this code in [HackerRank editorial](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/bash-tutorials---getting-started-with-conditionals/editorial).

```
read a
if [ `$a == "y" ] || [ $`a == "Y" ]; then
  echo "YES"
elif [ `$a == "n" ] || [ $`a == "N" ]; then
  echo "NO"
fi
```

Could anyone tell me what a single grave accent(`) before or after $ means? I searched and only found what `` means.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [backticks before bash command in shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/428644/backticks-before-bash-command-in-shell)

Comment: Formatting error.

Comment: I believe this is an formatting error on your reference site, which should most probably read `if [ "$a" == "y" ] || [ "$a" == "Y" ]; then ...`.

Comment: POSIX string comparison will take `=` just `[ "$a" = "y" ]` is sufficient

Comment: Funnily, while it is likely a typo, the code is not, by itself, syntactically wrong. You have a command substitution for the command `$a == "y" ] || [ $` (the second backtick just closes the first one), and what is actually executed, depends of course on what had been read into `a` before. Actually, it is two commands, where the second is only executed if the first returns a non-zero exit code.

Answer (score 2):

There is no meaning to the backticks in that piece of code. They are typos or formatting errors that will result in syntax errors.

A corrected version would use `"$a"` in all cases, and `=` in place of `==`.

Alternatively,

```
case "$a" in
    [yY]*) echo 'Yes' ;;
    [nN]*) echo 'No'  ;;
        *) echo 'Maybe'
esac
```